# How to reposition subcaptions in subfig?

Tags: graphics, captions, subcaption, subfig

This is my code.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[$K_4$]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.65]
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (4,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4)  to[out=50,in=40, distance=6cm] (4,0);


\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (0,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,4) circle [radius=0.1];

\node at (-.3,-.3) {$a$};
\node at (4.3,-.3) {$b$};
\node at (-.3,4.3) {$c$};
\node at (4.3,4.3) {$d$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hfill
\subfloat[$K_5$]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.65]
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (4,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4) -- (4,0);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4)  to[out=50,in=40, distance=6cm] (4,0);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0)  to[out=140,in=130, distance=6cm] (4,4);

\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (0,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (2,2) circle [radius=0.1];

\node at (-.3,-.3) {$a$};
\node at (4.3,-.3) {$b$};
\node at (-.3,4.3) {$c$};
\node at (4.3,4.3) {$d$};
\node at (2.4,2) {$e$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{$K_4$ is a planar graph and $K_5$ is a single-crossing graph}
\label{fig:k5k4}
\end{figure}
```

And this is what I am getting.

[image]

Is there a way to bring the subcaptions below the subfigures.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your sub cations are centered. Apparently you not like to be centered but below squares on images.

Comment: @Zarko Oh ok! Yes, could you please tell me how to do that? I am changing the question too.

Answer (score 2):

This solution puts extra white space to the left of the center (2,3).  I also trimmed excess white space from unknown cause.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]% freinds don't let frineds use [H]
\centering
\subfloat[$K_4$]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.65]
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (4,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\begin{scope}
  \clip (0,0) rectangle (6,6);
  \draw[][draw, thick] (0,4)  to[out=50,in=40, distance=6cm] (4,0);
\end{scope}


\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (0,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,4) circle [radius=0.1];

\node at (-.3,-.3) {$a$};
\node at (4.3,-.3) {$b$};
\node at (-.3,4.3) {$c$};
\node at (4.3,4.3) {$d$};

\path ($(current bounding box.east)!2!(2,3)$);% cnter square in image
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% show bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[$K_5$]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.65]
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (4,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4) -- (4,0);
\begin{scope}
  \clip (-2,0) rectangle (6,6);
  \draw[][draw, thick] (0,4)  to[out=50,in=40, distance=6cm] (4,0);
  \draw[][draw, thick] (0,0)  to[out=140,in=130, distance=6cm] (4,4);
\end{scope}

\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (0,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (2,2) circle [radius=0.1];

\node at (-.3,-.3) {$a$};
\node at (4.3,-.3) {$b$};
\node at (-.3,4.3) {$c$};
\node at (4.3,4.3) {$d$};
\node at (2.4,2) {$e$};
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% show bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{$K_4$ is a planar graph and $K_5$ is a single-crossing graph}
\label{fig:k5k4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

This version uses even less space, but you have to be careful not to overlap images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]% freinds don't let frineds use [H]
\centering
\subfloat[$K_4$]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.65]
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (4,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \draw[][draw, thick] (0,4)  to[out=50,in=40, distance=6cm] (4,0);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (0,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,4) circle [radius=0.1];

\node at (-.3,-.3) {$a$};
\node at (4.3,-.3) {$b$};
\node at (-.3,4.3) {$c$};
\node at (4.3,4.3) {$d$};

\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% show bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[$K_5$]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.65]
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (4,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,0) -- (4,4);
\draw[][draw, thick] (0,4) -- (4,0);
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \draw[][draw, thick] (0,4)  to[out=50,in=40, distance=6cm] (4,0);
  \draw[][draw, thick] (0,0)  to[out=140,in=130, distance=6cm] (4,4);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\draw[fill] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,0) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (0,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (4,4) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw[fill] (2,2) circle [radius=0.1];

\node at (-.3,-.3) {$a$};
\node at (4.3,-.3) {$b$};
\node at (-.3,4.3) {$c$};
\node at (4.3,4.3) {$d$};
\node at (2.4,2) {$e$};
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% show bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{$K_4$ is a planar graph and $K_5$ is a single-crossing graph}
\label{fig:k5k4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As supplement to nice @John Kormylo answer (+1). It should be used with some care: at positioning of sub-floats are considered only squares, so it can happened, that images in them will overlap. Also, images can overlap text above images.

This can be prevent with inserting `\vspace*{<v distance>}` after `\begin{figure}` and `\hspace{<h distance}`. Size of both distances can be determined by *trial-and-error* method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \vspace*{12mm}  % <-------
\subfloat[$K_4$]
{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[thick,fill] (0,0) node[below  left] {$a$} circle [radius=0.1] -- 
                  (4,4) node[above right] {$d$} circle [radius=0.1]
                  (0,4) node[above  left] {$c$} circle [radius=0.1]    
                  (4,0) node[below right] {$b$} circle [radius=0.1];
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \draw[thick] (0,4)  to[out=50,in=40, distance=6cm] (4,0);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
%
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west)
                rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% show bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\hspace{22mm}   % <-------
\subfloat[$K_5$]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[thick,fill] (0,0) node[below  left] {$a$} circle [radius=0.1] --
                  (4,4) node[above right] {$d$} circle [radius=0.1]
                  (0,4) node[above  left] {$c$} circle [radius=0.1] --
                  (4,0) node[below right] {$b$} circle [radius=0.1];
\node[right] at (2,2) {$e$};
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \draw[thick] (0,4)  to[out=50,in=40,   distance=6cm] (4,0);
  \draw[thick] (0,0)  to[out=140,in=130, distance=6cm] (4,4);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
%
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) 
                rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% show bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}
}
    \caption{$K_4$ is a planar graph and $K_5$ is a single-crossing graph}
    \label{fig:k5k4}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, your MWE is partly rewritten that be more compact and shorter.

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)